# How to setup admin user with gitlab with LDAP authentication?

Tags: authentication, ldap, gitlab

I've just setup gitlab, but I'm completely lost with regards to admin user. The wiki seems silent about this topic, and google hasn't been of help either.

So, how do I setup admin users with gitlab on LDAP authentication?

Comment: What version of GitLab is this for? Is this still applicable?

Comment: @PaulVerest I've since left the job of that gitlab installation, so I can answer what version it was (beyond just looking at the tag dates to see what was around at the time I asked the question). Nor do I use gitlab on my present job, so I can't answer whether it's still applicable.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can also set admin permissions to a user by doing something like this in the rails console:

```
User.find_by_email("user@example.org") do |i|
    i.admin = true
    i.save
end
```

Comment: How do I start/enter the gitlab rails console? Thanks/newbie

Comment: @user973956 try something like "cd /home/git/gitlab && RAILS_ENV=production rails console"

Comment: Does not work for me. After I enter that, I get a long output of the User object, but it still contains `admin: false`.

Comment: (from /home/git/gitlab) `sudo su git` then `bundle exec rails c production`

Comment: I just launched it with
sudo gitlab-rails console production
As described here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_root_password.html

Answer (score 28):

Mine is a  variant of the accepted answer but it's based on an example from the [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/security/reset_root_password.html)

From the command line of your gitlab server:

Open the gitlab rails console (I'm assuming here that you aren't logged in as root):

```
sudo gitlab-rails console production
```

Then type the following commands:

```
 user = User.find_by(username: 'my_username')
 user.admin = true
 user.save!
```

Close the console:

```
exit
```

Update your gitlab server:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Comment: This worked for me immediately after `user.save!` and browser refresh (without `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` or re-login).

Comment: Worked beautifully. No need to do `gitlab-ctl` though.

Comment: With gitlab newer versions, use `sudo gitlab-rails console -e production` to open the console

Answer (score 25):

This is what I did to make a LDAP (or Windows AD) user **vikas** as admin.

First login on GitLab portal and logout, then run the below commands.

```
gitlab-rails console production
u = User.where(id: 1).first
u.admin = true
u.save!
exit
```

After running the above commands, login again and now your will have admin privileges for **vikas** AD user.

Comment: I tested the above commands in Rails version 4.2.6 ( gitlab-rails --version ) and it works also without logging out of the gitlab. One can simply refresh the browser and the admin button ( Tools ) would appear. One just needs to be careful about the id number you pass in the command. In my case it was 3 ..... u = User.where(id: 3).first

Answer (score 6):

The file `db/fixtures/production/001_admin.rb` contains a user and password setup for administration, but you have to disable LDAP to login with it. Afterwards, if you have created a user by login in with LDAP, you can set it up to be an administrator and re-enable LDAP.

Hopefully, a more rational way exists...

Answer (score 4):

There is a check box on web interface, if your GitLab username has admin access.

Login to GitLab, and in the context of `Admin Area > Users > the.other.user > edit > Access > Access level`, check "Admin".

I didn't try the Linux commands, because web GUI is more reliable. The [official GitLab document about permission](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) didn't include this setting, maybe it feels like intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Login to gitlab database and run:

update users set admin = 't' where email like 'xxxxx@xxxxx';