# Can not find new project button on Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have two accounts,

One can not see the create new project button, but the other can.

I know it may be due to the setting of configuration file.

But the account only has 20 projects and the projects' size is under the limit.

```
max_size: 5242880000 # 5.megabytes*1000
```

[image]
[image]
here's my [gitlab.yml](https://gist.github.com/poc7667/9906965)

Comment: i have the same problem. have you found a solution?

Comment: I start the project manually, `rails s -p <PORT> -e production` then works

Answer (score 2):

In my instance I hit the 10 project limit (using version GitLab 7.12.2 30bffd5  (omnibus))
go to http://gitlab/admin/application_settings
and increase the limit.

(need to be logged in as admin=true (see  [How to setup admin user with gitlab with LDAP authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761396/how-to-setup-admin-user-with-gitlab-with-ldap-authentication/12915897#12915897) ))

Once you have done that you also need to edit the "Personal project limit for each user (which in my instance was also set to 10") at this page:
http://gitlab/admin/users/destroy-everything

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem resides in the gitlab.yml, I don't see anything wrong. You may have not given him the right **permissions**. I can't check it right now, but try creating [an admin user](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6483#issuecomment-37182942) and/or give to the user more level on an specific group and see if he can create project now (even though he must be able to create projects without been on a group, but it's worth a shoot).

The output of the following commands may be helpful, run them in the gitlab folder and edit your post whit the results:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
```